# Notepad takes 8 seconds to open

Tags: windows-7, performance, notepad

I have an i7-3930K with 32GB RAM, using 256GB SSD, running Win 7 Ultimate.

It takes 8 seconds to open notepad after going

> <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> -> notepad -> <kbd>enter</kbd>

Why is this so SLOW? WTF?

Don't suggest virus/malware please.

**EDIT:** understood this is hard to answer. So perhaps we could answer how to troubleshoot?
I am looking at taskmgr / resource monitor and nothing looks unusual (cpu hardly being used, 10% memory usage). Plenty of space on SSD.

Taskmgr opens instantly.

cmd opens in about 8 seconds too. so irritating.

**Edit:** both take same time to open as shortcut/exe.

**EDIT:** After reboot- they are now opening instantly. So what could it have been? Should I be worried? Is it likely to be the health of my primary SSD drive? What could I do to test the SSD drive performance???

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this in any meaningful way. If I had to hazard a guess... is your drive nearly full or heavily used? SSDs can have IO problems if not taken care of.

Comment: Hmm. Does notepad open quickly if run from the .exe or from a shortcut?

Comment: Use Process Monitor to see what is slow: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Comment: Could your SSD have switched from DMA to PIO somehow? Probably not, but I can't think of anything else...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and changed the contents of the "Start in" field from %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% to the explicit path of My Documents in every known shotcut (Desktop, taskbar, start menu). Since then, Notepad opens instantly.

Comment: This actually makes sense. Default Windows apps take long time for me in VDI machine, but other apps don't - they execute directly with absolute path, but Windows apps have to resolve paths, with some of them being over a remote server (to persist files and some settings), which is slower